# Address of local variable on stack

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, stack, stack-overflow

I wrote a little C code, opened it in GDB, put a breakpoint on line `exploit = (long long *)&exploit+2;` and run the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char Shellcode[] = "\x48\xc7\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00"
                   "\x48\xc7\xc3\x1a\x00\x00\x00"
                   "\xcd\x80";

int main()
{
        long long *exploit;
        exploit = (long long *)&exploit+2;
        *exploit = (long long)Shellcode;
        return 0;
}
```

Since the breakpoint is set on line `exploit = (long long *)&exploit+2;`, GDB stops the execution of program before executing that line and it'd mean that only the line `long long *exploit;`, which brings `exploit` into existence has been executed.

At this point I was expecting `exploit` to reside on the top of the stack because it's the only local variable and local variables stay on the top of stack after calling a function(Please correct me if I'm wrong). Turns out it's not the case.

```
(gdb) print /x &exploit 
$2 = 0x7fffffffdfe8
(gdb) x/6xg $rsp
0x7fffffffdff0: 0x0000555555554690      0x00007ffff7a5a2b1
0x7fffffffe000: 0x0000000000040000      0x00007fffffffe0d8
0x7fffffffe010: 0x00000001f7b9b288      0x0000555555554660
```

As we can see that the top of the element is `0x7fffffffdff0` while the address of exploit is 8 bytes above the stack pointer(Above? How could it be?) at `0x7fffffffdfe8`. Can someone explain it to me?

**Edit:**

disassembling the main function gives:

```
0x555555554660 <main>           push   %rbp                                                                                                                         │
   │0x555555554661 <main+1>         mov    %rsp,%rbp                                                                                                                    │
B+>│0x555555554664 <main+4>         lea    -0x8(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                              │
   │0x555555554668 <main+8>         add    $0x10,%rax                                                                                                                   │
   │0x55555555466c <main+12>        mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)                                                                                                              │
   │0x555555554670 <main+16>        mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax                                                                                                              │
   │0x555555554674 <main+20>        lea    0x2009b5(%rip),%rdx        # 0x555555755030 <Shellcode>                                                                      │
   │0x55555555467b <main+27>        mov    %rdx,(%rax)                                                                                                                  │
   │0x55555555467e <main+30>        mov    $0x0,%eax                                                                                                                    │
   │0x555555554683 <main+35>        pop    %rbp                                                                                                                         │
   │0x555555554684 <main+36>        retq
```

**Edit-2: What does this code do?**

If the variable `exploit` resides at the top of stack(as I predicted it to be), the next 8 bytes below `exploit` would be RBP followed by the return address of an instruction in __libc_start_main() function(The function that sets up environment for execution of program, calls main(), and then cleans up the mess after execution).

`exploit = (long long *)&exploit+2;` would shift and make the exploit to point the return address I mentioned and `*exploit = (long long)Shellcode;` would overwrite the return address with the address of `Shellcode`. Since the `Shellcode` is opcodes of pre-examined instructions and is readable by the processor, it'd be executed once the program finishes executing and tries to get back to __libc_start_main() using the return address, provided that the DEP is turned off.

Comment: C language doesn't know anything about a stack. How your stack is working depends on architecture. Which architecture are you talking about?

Comment: @Gerhardh: I'm using i5 intel processor and 64-bit architecture.

Comment: On intel CPUs, EBP is used to address variables on stack.

Comment: While the variable is visible with respect to its lifetime, this does not mean that the compiler already created code to use it in this line. You don't initialize it. Therefore things might change in the next line...

Comment: @Gerhardh: I understand that the EBP/RBP is used to address variable on stack using indirect addressing mode. 8(%RBP), -16(%RBP), etc. But I don't understand the concept you mentioned that things might change in next line!! Could you, please, point me to some resources so I could read and understand exactly how it works?

Comment: Variables have a lifetime defined by C language. Within that lifetime the compiler can optimize based on usage of that variable. It might happen that you cannot inspect contents of a variable before its first usage or after its last usage. The involved registers might not yet be adjusted correctly. You might show a bit more of the assembly code of this function.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Edited the question to include disassembled main function.

Comment: Now you can see that your variable is located at [RBP]-8 which is the expected address.

Comment: Maybe because you are not calling any other function, optimizer removed increasing (and decreasing) of stack pointer.

Comment: @Gerhardh: But now the question is if there reside a variable above the value of RSP then why has RSP not been updated to point to the new top of the stack. I just stepped through one sentence of code in GDB and executed `exploit = (long long *)&exploit+2;` but RSP still points to the same address and has not been updated to the new top of stack.

Comment: This code contains so many type inconsistencies and strict aliasing violations that the compiler is free to do pretty much anything. There is no predictable outcome of this program and therefore no memory allocations can be predicted either.

Comment: @Lundin: That comment does not contribute anything to the discussion. The output of the code is pretty much predictable. Please read the Edit-2 I just made to the original question.

Comment: The sysv abi provides a 128 byte red zone that can be used without adjusting the stack pointer.

Comment: Of course it does contribute, as the compiler is free to 1) allocate the variable wherever it wants 2) allocate it in a CPU register 3) not allocate it at all. Option 3 is a likely result if your code contains strict aliasing violations. Similarly, it does not need to generate any code manipulating that variable.

Comment: @Lundin: But the compiler did allocate the space for `exploit` and also manipulated all the expected variables accordingly. The only thing that didn't go as palnned was the change of RSP to it's new top.

Comment: There is no "as planned" since the program contains multiple cases of undefined behavior.

Comment: @7_R3X you probably understand this well, but just to make it clearly stated... exploits are created around what compiler *does* produce - for particular source, under particular conditions. Not the other way around, that you write exploit, and you expect the compiler to cope and produce something particular. Usually any subtle change in anything may lead compiler to produce different binary, rendering the original exploit useless. But there's little chance to write exploits without exploiting particular UB, so that's why it may break any time and works usually only for specific binary.

Comment: @Ped7g: +1 for your explanation. I'm very new to exploit writing and every piece of information/suggestion is helping me to understand it better. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SYS V ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) introduced a number of optimisations, including (as [Jester pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565594/address-of-local-variable-on-stack#comment78092676_45565594)) the [Red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) - a 128 bytes area below<sup>1</sup> the stack pointer that is not touched by any asynchronous handler.
In the case of a leaf function, the compiler can use the Red zone for storing the local variables without moving `rsp`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that you appear to use the inverse terminology for what is "above" and "below" the stack pointer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those links. I was looking more for the resources than the actual answer. :)